# How can I detect Context Menu->Select All event in the browser?

Tags: browser, codemirror, dom-events

We're using CodeMirror for an XML Editor component we have.
In it, is has lots of listeners, which on of them is Select All (CTRL-A). It listens to the combinations of CTRL and A, and reworks the select all internally (since it is composed of many span and div elements).

When the user right clicks on a text and clicks "Select All" it doesn't fire the same event as CTRL-A.
So my question is: What is the event for Right click (context-menu) and then Select All?

Comment: I want to ask you ,How I can to show (context-menu) in codemirror ? @Asaf Mesika